# Зачем нужен макрос PATH_MAX если ограничения на абсолютный путь на самом деле нет?

Tags: linux, c

При работе с ФС обнаружил, что макрос PATH_MAX на самом деле не работает, то есть в буфер с размером в PATH_MAX не вмещается полный путь к директории.
Я решил определить скриптом максимально возможную длину адсолютного пути, я дошел до ~130791(что примерно в 32 раза больше PATH_MAX на моей системе) символов, дальше shell оболочка dash перестала запускать какие либо программы и создание дерикторий стало невозможным, но судя по всему это проблема только самой shell оболочки и ограничения нет.
Хотелось бы узнать, зачем нужен этот макрос если на самом деле ограничения судя по всему нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PATH_MAX` — это наибольшая длина пути (абсолютного или относительного), который возможно передать в системный вызов, например `open()` откажется открывать файл и установит `errno` в `ENAMETOOLONG`, если ему передать путь длиннее. Это связано с тем, что ядро копирует аргументы в своё адресное пространства, и дабы избежать злоупотребления этим необходимо ограничивать размер аргументов.

Обработка путей длиннее полностью лежит на плечах программиста. Например, чтобы открыть подобный файл можно сделать один или несколько `chdir()` и только затем `open()` с относительным путём, или воспользоваться `openat()`.

Вопреки заблуждению, `PATH_MAX` никогда не был (да поправят меня историки) ни максимальной длиной абсолютного пути, который может существовать в системе, ни какой-либо конкретной ФС. По природе иерархичности и разнообразия ФС *nix'ов такое ограничение просто невозможно навязать.

Кроме того существуют пара библиотечных функций, которые также всё ещё полагаются на ограничение размера буферов в `PATH_MAX`. Самый примечательный пример — `realpath()`.